# Menubar App: Desktop Switch Bug

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I have build a cocoa mac application which is a menubar app. When you click it, it opens a NSWindow.

The problem:
1. When I open the menubar app on Desktop1. 
2. Then go to Desktop2 and open the app by clicking the menubar icon, the app opens, but the desktop moves back to Desktop1 !

It's a rather tricky thing.

I appreciate your help !
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting your [window collection behavior](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000013-SW24) to `NSWindowCollectionBehaviorCanJoinAllSpaces` so that, well, it isn't restrained to a single desktop.

```
[newWindow setCollectionBehavior:NSWindowCollectionBehaviorCanJoinAllSpaces];
```

`NSWindowCollectionBehaviorMoveToActiveSpace` should also work, but is a little more finicky.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't solve it. Maybe I should add that we have a window that flips around (like widgets) when a button is clicked. So it has 2 panels. Front & Back. And it seems like the Back panel is always still assigned with the wrong desktop.

Comment: @cocoacoder Not sure what you mean by 2 panels - you mean, two different NSPanels? Or just 2 views?

Comment: found the bug. It was a wrong window property (guessed it..) Thanks anyways! Have a Question Answered tag !